# Can't cast the result of LAG or LEAD into an Integer

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have been trying to do a calculation based on the result of either the LAG or LEAD functions.

Encapsulating the function in the INTEGER() casting function seems to cause an issue with the OVER function within and throws the following error:

**Unrecognized Analytic Function: INT64 cannot be used with an OVER() clause**

The following is the base code that works just fine, but when I add a function, it produces an error:

LEAD(hits.hitNumber, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID, visitid, visitnumber ORDER BY hits.hitNumber DESC) as nextHit

The code that I was using to produce this error is as follows:

INTEGER(LEAD(hits.hitNumber, 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID, visitid ORDER BY hits.hitNumber DESC) as nextHit

The following doesn't seem to work either:

INTEGER(LEAD(hits.hitNumber, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID, visitid ORDER BY hits.hitNumber DESC))as nextHit

**Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 8, column 36. Was expecting: ")"**

Do I really need to make this a sub-query to make this work or is there a different solution?

Comment: What about moving `INTEGER()` inside the `LEAD()` function? As in, `LEAD(INTEGER(hits.hitNumber, 1) ...`

Answer (score 1):

2 possible solutions:

As Jordan says, bring the INTERGER() cast inside LEAD():

```
SELECT LEAD(INTEGER(hits.hitNumber), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID, visitid, visitnumber ORDER BY hits.hitNumber DESC) as nextHit
FROM [dataset.ga_sessions_20140107]
```

Or as in your suggestion, with a sub-query:

```
SELECT INTEGER(nextHit) FROM (
  SELECT LEAD(hits.hitNumber, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID, visitid, visitnumber ORDER BY hits.hitNumber DESC) as nextHit
  FROM [dataset.ga_sessions_20140107]
)
```